# Typescript / Node.js - How to mock transitive dependencies for integration testing?

Tags: node.js, typescript, supertest, proxyquire

Let say I have an Express route which is handled by a controller. The controller uses a service and the service uses a repository to talk to a data source.

I want to create an integration test using [Supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) to test that route :

```
test -> my Express app -> controller -> service -> repository -> data source
```

My problem is that I need to *mock* the repository/data source, to run the test! I want to hardcode some values as if they were coming from the real data source. What are my options?

In a Java world, I would be using dependency injection with Spring or Guice and I would replace the repository with a mock version that way. What are the patterns to achieve such mocking in a Typescript/Node.js world?

I guess using plain Javascript I could use `Proxyquire` and its [Globally override require](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire#globally-override-require) feature, to mock the repository from the test itself. But I'm not sure this works well with Typescript.

So what are the recommended ways of mocking a "deep" component (a transitive dependency) from within a test file, using Typescript and Node.js?

Comment: If you're using plain Node rather than Typescript, there's a beautiful library by the creator of passport called [electrolyte](https://github.com/jaredhanson/electrolyte) which does dependency injection/IoC. You set up folders that it will look up in reverse order using its `IoC.use(..)` function, so in my test bootstrap file I add my mocks folders so that it looks there first, and will resolve my mock data source instead of the data source in my other folders or node modules.

Comment: I created a testing library for Typescript that makes it very easy to mock dependencies, no matter where they are in the dependency chain: [ts-mock-imports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mock-imports)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded, so you can just load them first in your test file and stub them using a library like sinon.

Consider the following code:

```
// dependency.ts
export function foo(){
    return 'foo';
}

// app.ts
import {foo} from './dependency';
export default function main(){
    return  'winner ' + foo();
}
```

You could test app.ts stubbing its dependency with sinon in the following way:

```
import * as Dependency from '../src/dependency';
import main from '../src/app';

describe('test dependency', () => {
    var fooStub;
    beforeEach(() => {
        fooStub = sinon.stub(Dependency, 'foo');
        fooStub.returns('la la lang');
    });
    afterEach(()=>{
        fooStub.restore();
    })

    it('uses stubbed dependency', ()=>{
        expect(main()).to.be.equal('winner la la lang');
    });

    it('can return different values on other tests', ()=>{
        fooStub.returns('moonlight');
        expect(main()).to.be.equal('winner moonlight');
    });
});
```

So basically for your integration tests you can import and stub your dependencies before starting the app. I have done this creating an `app.proxy.ts` file:

- In `app.proxy` import your repository and stub it to return the predefined data. After setting up the stub, import the real `app.ts` and export it.
- In your integration test file, import `app.proxy` instead of app and use it with supertest. This will give you the app in the end, but after setting up the stubbed dependency!
- write and run the test, knowing it will use the predefined data